# Relationship between namespaces and folders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, directory, namespaces

Hi all I have a problem with namespaces.

As you can see the Standard Assets are imported but the script does not see the UnityStandardAssets namespace.

[image: namespace can't be found]

But if I create a new script inside the Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/testScript.cs there is no problem

[image: namespace resolved]

Clearly there is some kind of relationship between namespaces and folders that I do not understand.
I would very much appreciate if somebody could shine some light on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

No they are no relation between namespaces and folders, but in general its common usage to adapt the namespce with name folder. when you are using an externall, the contains specified namespaces..

so in same project you could write that

namespace toto
{
public class titi{}
}

namespace tata
{
public class titi{}
}

and if you want to use titi in namespace tata

you write

```
var t = new tata.titi();
```

or put

```
using tata;
var t = new titi();
```

but its good usage to use namespace, for example when you want to categorize some part of program.

so in your sample, you could put off the unused using directive (namespaces) (quick fix does the operation)

By default all classes that don't have an explicit namespace belong to global namespace, so even when you are not writing any namespace you are using one

#### 3rd party edit

From the comments below

> Java, as you already know enforces the namespace to match the folder (which can be annoying).

But in C# this is not the case - you can put the files in whatever folder you like and the namespace does not have to reflect this folder structure.

Comment: Thank you for the time to answer :). Unfortunately i don't understand. You can have one class in two namespaces ? I am new to C# , in Java namespaces and folders are 1:1 and that makes things much simpler. And that doesn't explain why a namespace is visible from one file and not from the other. But again thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: what you dont understant? namespace is just the name of container, where you could put classes..that's all!!  and when you want access from one container to a class to another containe, you have to indicate in what container you want to access to desired class.

Comment: By default all classes that don't have an explicit namespace belong to global namespace, so even when you are not writing any namespace you are using one

Comment: You can have a class with the same name in two different namespaces, but they are two different classes. The whole point of namespaces is to give types a unique name so that collisions in type names don't happen. The fully qualified name of a type includes the namespace, e.g. `Somenamespace.YourClass`. Adding a `using Somenamespace` at the top of a file brings that namespace into the scope of the file so you no longer need to fully qualify it, but really it's still `Somenamespace.YourClass`. Folders are just folders, though generally they do have parity with the namespace.

Comment: By default, visual studio will assume when you create a c# file in a folder that the namespace will be a combination of the folder names leading to the file, though this is not enforced and you can freely change the namespace. Java, as you already know enforces the namespace to match the folder (which can be annoying).

Comment: Thanks guys. It looks like the problem I'm having is Unity3d specific. There is no reason C# wise why a file in Assets/Scripts wouldn't be aware of a class in Assets/StandardAssets. Thanks for clearing up the namespace / folder thing.